# Meaning of the phrase "push opinions"

Tags: meaning

Here it goes in context:

> People don't like to push opinions about politics.

Does it mean that people do not like give their opinions on politics or ask?

Comment: Source? I think something is missing. Generally, you *push* something on someone. Your example doesn't have a *someone*.

Comment: Please remember to cite your initial research, for example, looking up words in dictionaries for meanings that may be unfamiliar to you. OALD *[push](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/push_1): to try hard to persuade people to accept or agree with a new idea, buy a new product, etc.* You can push push a new exercise regimen, push a new brand of diet soda, push a different philosophy of disciplining children, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Pushing" in the context of giving opinions or views carries a context of trying to persuade others in a forceful way. A person may be described as "*pushy*" if they are excessively assertive about any subject.

Someone described as "pushing their opinions upon others" means they are trying to persuade others to take on the same opinions, or perhaps trying to present their opinion as the only valid one.

**eg.**

> "Please stop pushing your views about veganism on me."

It is somewhat different to the term "peddling", an old-fashioned word for "selling" that has come to be a pejorative term describing someone who spreads their views or ideas:

**eg.**

> "A former Alaska lawmaker has pleaded guilty to a state count of letting unregistered lobbyists peddle their ideas to him."

"Peddling" carries the idea of spreading views to as wide an audience as possible, whereas "pushing upon" more suggests trying to persuade a specific, possibly captive audience.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, 'pushing opinions' references the general activity of discussing something more than simply voicing one's opinion on a matter. Viewing *this specific sentence* in a broader context, politics is generally a touchy topic for discussion. People shy away from discussing it.

Likely, this sentence is about *giving* an opinion on politics, not asking for one.

Comment: Or maybe it's even stronger than _giving_. Maybe it's _giving and trying to persuade_. That's what I think of when I hear "pushing an opinion".